# Trying to pivot by keeping a fixed column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with pandas data frames. Suppose I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6]})
```

and I want to have something looking like

```
import numpy as np
arrays = [np.array(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']),np.array(['x', 'y','x', 'y','x', 'y'])]
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,4,2,5,3,6], index=arrays)
```

But to keep the 'name' heading.

(apologies I'm not sure how to make the code bits compile here and show the data frames explicitly).

For some reason I am struggling to do this with my (much larger) data set.

What I have tried:

1. Using df.groupby('name')

But this gives me a 'groupie' object and I don't know what to do with it.

2. Using .pivot

Not working because I'm trying to keep the 'names' fixed.

3. Using .stack

This is giving me

```
   0  name    a
   x       1
   y       4
1  name    b
   x       2
   y       5
2  name    c
   x       3
   y       6
dtype: object
```

i.e. a single layer index object rather than double layer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.set_index('name').stack().to_frame()
```

---

```
# print(df1)
        0
name     
a    x  1
     y  4
b    x  2
     y  5
c    x  3
     y  6
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to *drop* the index and was hoping the gene_symbol index was automatically replace it, rather than re-set the index. That was so silly of me! Will accept when time allows